Oracle own aggregation function in package
I created my own Oracle type and aggregation function from it:
As separate one, the function is created as:
create or replace FUNCTION MY_AGGR_FN (input NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING MY_AGGR_TYPE;

It works fine! Now I'd like to put this function into pwn package but I do not see how to create package body from this.
This is my package declaration:
create or replace PACKAGE MY_PKG AS 

  FUNCTION MY_AGGR_FN(n NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;

END MY_PKG;

But in package body I cannot just put:
create or replace PACKAGE BODY MY_PKG AS

  FUNCTION MY_AGGR_FN(n NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
  PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING MY_AGGR_TYPE;

END MY_PKG;


If you want it to compile without errors then you need to include PARALLEL_ENABLE in the function header in the package signature and then it will compile without errors. However, it still will not be useable as an aggregation function because you haven't included the AGGREGATE clause in the package signature (and you cannot do that).

You cannot define an aggregation function in the public signature of a package as the syntax does not allow it.

The CREATE FUNCTION documentation gives the syntax for a stand-alone function as:

create_function ::=

plsql_function_source ::=


The CREATE PACKAGE documentation gives the syntax for a package function signature as:

package_function_declaration ::=


While a stand-alone function can include the AGGREGATE clause in its signature, a package function signature does not allow that option (and also does not allow the Invokers Rights, Default Collation or SQL Macro clauses).
So:
CREATE TYPE FirstAggregationType AS OBJECT(
  value NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT FirstAggregationType
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT FirstAggregationType,
    value       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT FirstAggregationType,
    returnValue    OUT NUMBER,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT FirstAggregationType,
    ctx         IN OUT FirstAggregationType
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY FirstAggregationType
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT FirstAggregationType
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := FirstAggregationType( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT FirstAggregationType,
    value       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT FirstAggregationType,
    returnValue    OUT NUMBER,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT FirstAggregationType,
    ctx         IN OUT FirstAggregationType
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    self.value := COALESCE( self.value, ctx.value );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE tools IS
  FUNCTION FIRST( value NUMBER )
  RETURN NUMBER PARALLEL_ENABLE;
END tools;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY tools IS
  FUNCTION FIRST( value NUMBER )
  RETURN NUMBER PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING FirstAggregationType;
END tools;
/

Will compile but if you try to use it:
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, group_id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 13, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 13,    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 13,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 28,    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 28, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 28,    4 FROM DUAL;

SELECT group_id,
       Tools.First( value ) AS first_value
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY group_id;

You get the exception:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Since the function signature does not define it as an aggregation function.
If you try to modify the package signature to add the AGGREGATE clause:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tools IS
  FUNCTION FIRST( value NUMBER )
  RETURN NUMBER PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE;
END tools;
/

Then you get the exception:
PLS-00220: simple name required in this context

fiddle

Unfortunately aggregate function cannot be embedded in package. Thanks for prompt response.
